# Java write deserializing interface for Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, deserialization

I want to write a Java interface that has a method that allows to deserialize an object.
The interface looks like this:

```
public interface IObjectizable {

    <T> T  toObject(InputStream inputStream);
}
```

Now I'm stuck on implementing the interface. The interface should be applicable an all kinds of objects. Want to use this method in a MessageBodyWriter in Jersey. The MessageBodyWriter looks like this:

```
public class LinkDataDemarshaller<T> implements MessageBodyReader<T>  {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {

        if(IObjectizable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {

            return true;
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T readFrom(Class<T> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        IObjectizable obj = (IObjectizable) genericType;

        return obj.toObject(entityStream);
    }
```

My question is how to I implement the toObject method correctly? I tried the following but this doesn't work and gives me a Type miss match error.

```
@Override
public <T> T toObject(InputStream inputStream) {

    return new String("test");
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Greetings

Comment: Your method must return something of type T, not String (your last example mentioning the error); Why dont you just make your interface method's return-type Object instead of a generic? `<T> Object toObject(InputStream in);`

Comment: Thanks for your input I tried to change my code and it seems to work now. Since the MessageBodyReader`` casts the object correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the interface in the way [Vince Emigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2398375/vince-emigh) suggested it. I don't know if this is best practice. Maybe a better solution would be to create a factory that creates objects instead of an interface. So if you have any further advice please let me know. :)

The `IObjectizable` Inteface:

```
public interface IObjectizable {

    Object  toObject(InputStream inputStream);
}
```

The implemented `MessageBodyReader` interface:

```
@Provider 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class LinkDataDemarshaller implements MessageBodyReader<Object>  {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {

        if(IObjectizable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {

            return true;
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        try {

            Object obj = type.newInstance();
            IObjectizable interfaceObj = ((IObjectizable) obj); 

            return interfaceObj.toObject(entityStream);
        } 
        catch (InstantiationException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;            
        } 
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }           
    }
}
```